# Can someone figure out the encryption method?

Tags: encryption

Is there a way to decrypt a database if I know the encrypted and decrypted state of the data? We have old software at work (VB) that needs rewriting, problem is that the database is encrypted. I can query the old software for individual entries, and see the corresponding encrypted data in the DB, but the database is about 1000 entries long and I wouldn't want to do this by hand. I can give you some examples:

```
Unencrypted Data   Corresponding encrypted data
0264/592636        /2Q0Z3MfVTGAgILN2krVfmp+lYs=
0264/591410        /2Q0Z3MfVTGAlWGWetMmvNarF6s=
0264/591548        /2Q0Z3MfVTGAlWNdmW96pgsiQxE=
0264/402559        /2Q0Z3MfUzia9nqAJug5dVxNbto=
0364/888890        /2Q0Z3MfakAgSr1LCbMmjJ6D6tM=
```

Comment: The encryption key must be there somewhere.

Comment: I can tell you, however it's encrypted it's vulnerable to a dictionary attack, as 0264/ encrypts to the same thing each time.

Comment: But much easier to find the VB code that does the encrypting/decrypting

Comment: @ewanm89 Actually, 0364/ also encrypts to the same, assuming it's not a typo.

Comment: @Luc sure that isn't a typo as the VTGA also matches the 59...

Comment: @ewanm89 true. +1.

Comment: @Luc Contacting the guy that wrote the code was the first thing I tried. No luck there. Also, 0364/ is not a typo as you already guessed. I'm quite new to decrypting stuff. The only reason I tried to do it is because the same sets of numbers seemed to encrypt in the same way every time, so at a first glance it looked trivial, so a question for the experts would be: "Shoud I give up, and just have someone rewrite the entries by hand or is this worth pursuing?

Comment: Have you tried some kind of VB decompiler?

Comment: @Mike Couldn't you automate that query process you are able to do? That would get you around that whole encryption issue. If you have a GUI app, maybe you can AutoHotKey your 1000 records out of there for example.

Comment: @Mike Another suggestion, sort of like my suggestion #3: Can't you write some script that calls the decrypt function for all database entries? Make it click the right buttons with AutoIt or something?

Comment: Ok, I'm a little further along :). After base64 and some little adjustments I managed to get to this :
4091923 is encoded as 533898AC19FC611A75E7C1E9769E

Comment: 211281 is encoded as 4BCD86BDEAC410DC099423B4A50C
290931 is encoded as 4BC506A4213A0808FD91595FA6B3
415252 is encoded as 533B927F886A36CA026F27C925C7
433568 is encoded as 53397FA35CA6C1033AD26FA965C8
433565 is encoded as 53397FA35CA6CCFAFBC5B54961FD

Answer (score 4):

There are three solutions here:

1. Try to find the encryption method. It can be something custom, it can be encrypted in all sorts of weird ways, and you might need a key from somewhere. This is what you are trying to do now.
2. Find the code that encrypts/decrypts the data.
3. Write a script that simply calls the decrypt function for all records.

I'm not sure which is easier, 2 or 3, but trying to figure out what kinda code this is doesn't seem like the way to go.

Moreover, this is a problem specifically for you. It's not useful for future readers if it was solved using solution 1, thus the question would be closed as too localized.

I don't know why you didn't try solution 2 actually, can't you read VB well enough to find it or so? I don't mean it accusing, but if you can't find the code or script something to fix it (solution 3), you might want to find someone who can. It would probably save you (and anyone trying to find what encryption it is) a lot of time.

Comment: Hi Luc, thanks for your answer. I'd love to look at the old VB code, however, the sources left 5 years ago, with the guy that wrote them. So I'll admit to being lazy occasionally, but that's not the reason I didn't try looking at the sources :-). Thank you for your other suggestions though.

Comment: @Mike even if you don't have the sources it may be possible to reverse engineer the binaries

Comment: @Mike You could also try contacting him.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry now I got your task. You basically want to find the Key right??? This is not an easy task even if you have matching plaintext-ciphertext pairs. It falls in the area of cryptanalysis which is a topic of its own. You can read about it for further details.

Comment: Only have to find a key if applicable. We don't even know if it's an encryption algorithm, or merely a form of encoding. Gotta figure out what converted the data it in the first place.

Comment: @green: This kind of questions/comments should not go into an answer itself, but should be attached to the question as a comment.